# Mysql ordering and then grouping a query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I need to order my query by date first...

So I used this:

```
SELECT * FROM `mfw_navnode` order by `id` DESC
```

I wanted to order my results from last to first.

Then what I am trying to do

is to add a query over it, which would group my results by node_name..

The result should be..all the top nodes grouped by "category/node name type", while the first node that I see is was ordered the highest for its category in the first query..

I thought to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM( 
SELECT * FROM `mfw_navnode` order by `id` DESC) AS DD
WHERE (node_name='Eby' OR node_name='Laa'  OR node_name='MIF' OR node_name='Amaur' OR node_name='Asn' )
GROUP BY DD.node_name
```

I get no result..or any response from phpmyadmin when I input that result..

Where do I get wrong?

Note , I dont want to group my results and then order them..

I want them to be ordered, and then grouped. After being grouped..I want the result of each group to have the highest value ..from the other rows in the group

Comment: Can you include a sample set and what the result should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not sufficient to perform the ordering first, as even then MySQL makes no guarantee over which record it will select for each group.  From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html):

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

You must instead identify the records of interest with a subquery, then join the result with your table again in order to obtain the related values:

```
SELECT *
FROM   mfw_navnode NATURAL JOIN (
         SELECT node_name, MAX(id) AS id FROM mfw_navnode GROUP BY node_name
       ) AS DD
WHERE  node_name IN ('Eby', 'Laa', 'MIF', 'Amaur', 'Asn')
```

Comment: Nice answer... you have enlightened me.. very close to the solution but it isnt

Answer (score 0):

Ordered by ID and group by node_name

```
SELECT * FROM `mfw_navnode`
WHERE (node_name='Eby' OR node_name='Laa'  OR node_name='MIF' OR node_name='Amaur' OR node_name='Asn' )
GROUP BY DD.node_name
ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Grouping is used commonly when You are using some aggregate function (sum, max, min, count, etc). If You don't use such function in Your query then why do You want to group the results?

Anyway, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT *
FROM mfw_navnode
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
    FROM mfw_navnode
    WHERE node_name IN ('Eby', 'Laa', 'MIF', 'Amaur', 'Asn')
    GROUP BY node_name)
ORDER BY id
```

Answer (score -1):

The following SQL may yield you the required output:

```
SELECT node_name, MAX(id)
FROM mfw_navnode
GROUP BY node_name
ORDER BY node_name
```

Answer (score -1):

I see two problems with your SQL.

1) placing the order by in the inline select does nothing (and is probably causing an error)
2) you are grouping on node_name but you are not aggregating anything

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as row_count, node_name FROM( SELECT * FROM mfw_navnode ) AS DD
WHERE (node_name='Eby' OR node_name='Laa'  OR node_name='MIF' OR node_name='Amaur' OR node_name='Asn' )
GROUP BY DD.node_name
order by node_name desc
```

further I am not sure why you need the inline select as the where could simply be on the original select ( perhaps you have something more complex going on that you didn't show )

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as row_count, node_name 
from mfw_navnode
WHERE node_name='Eby' OR node_name='Laa'  OR node_name='MIF' OR node_name='Amaur' OR node_name='Asn' 
GROUP BY node_name
order by node_name desc
```